treating cron service as request
I have a function that repeatedly uses a service of type 'scope: Request'. This service obtains a variable from the request header and uses it for further work.
@Injectable({
  scope: Scope.REQUEST
})
export class Service {

  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request
  ) {}

  private getXXX(){
    return this.request.header('XXX').split(' ')[1];
  }

}

I would like to put this function additionally in a cron job. This causes the cron job service to not build with the note 'because it is defined in a non static provider.'
@Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_DAY_AT_MIDNIGHT)
private handleCronJobs(){}

WARN [Scheduler] Cannot register cron job "Service@handleCronJobs" because it is defined in a non static provider.

Is it possible to give the call type 'Request' from the cron service?

Why does the cron service need this request scoped service?

If you are injecting your Request Scoped Service into your CronJobService this won't work. Since your service is request scoped the cron job service won't be able to instantiate the service because cron jobs have no request object.
More info on this: NestJS: Injected dependencies are undefined during cron job execution
What you could do is remove the scope: Scope.Request and use the default behavior for it work (as a singleton), that should do the trick. If you are planning to use the request headers for your service I would advice you to pass that as a function's parameter instead directly from the controller you might be calling it from
